# Excel Interop, Clearing changes made since last save

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, vba

I have an Excel sheet that I use. I iterate a given number of times (goes over a thousand times) replacing certain cells with values and then using Excel to calculate a couple of formulas. I manipulate excel using the `Range.Value2` and `Range.Formula` arrays.
After each iteration I want to bring Excel back to its original state, by clearing changes made since last save. However I'm struggling to find anything on this, so far I've tried calling `Application.Undo()` however that does not work.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please utilize the code below:

```
Excel.Application xlApp ;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


    xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("Yourworkbook");

    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    ....do your stuff

    xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);

    xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Although not clearly stated by the poster - this code actually uses the parameters of the close method, the first option being SaveChanges set to false. This does work as per the question to not prompt to save changes on closing the file, thus returning the file to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

```
using excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO
```

You can try saving a copy before changing the sheet, then load from the saved copy after your done.

```
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
wb.SaveAs(CopyPath); 
File.Move(CopyPath, path);
```

Comment: That is one of the options , however since I am doing allot of iterations , it will be quite slow doing that after each iteration.Thanks though.

Comment: @Tohmas It really depends on the size of the file and the times ran through. To me it sounds like you should just use a template. Read from the template, do your changes then,close it and load it again for the next changes.

Answer (score 0):

.Undo() method is completely useless when called after code automation.
It is only designed to work on user operations.

As the answer above, follow the pattern of...
1. save current state - to a seperate workbook file.
2. modify current state into new state.
3. restore back file using the original from step 1.

You can add some buttons to the ribbon for this process.